# Parameterized SQL queries and optimize PHP code for user registration

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Pretty new to PHP here and I have been looking into how to use parameterized queries for my SQL connections. But everything I look at makes me think that I need to be changing the same values every time for parameterized queries to be of use. Is there any way to shrink what I am currently doing with my queries using parameterized queries? Am I reading into these things wrong?

I may be new to PHP, but I know enough, in general, to know that this code is pretty shitty. I don't like having multiple select * queries and then referencing fields I need by association. But I also had problems not doing it this way. Can someone take a quick glance at this and nudge me in the right direction? I'm prepared to be called dumb, so bring it. :) Thanks.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // initializing variables
    $username = "";
    $email    = "";
    $errors = array(); 

    // connect to the database
    $db = mysqli_connect('db_server', 'db_user', 'db_pw', 'db_name');

    // REGISTER USER
    if (isset($_POST['register-submit'])) {
      // receive all input values from the form
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['reg_username']);
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['reg_email']);
      $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['reg_password_1']);
      $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['reg_password_2']);
      $actcode  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['reg_actcode']);

      // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
      // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
      if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
      if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
      if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
      if ($password_1 != $password_2) { array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match"); }
      if ($actcode != "tobecaps") { array_push($errors, "Wrong activation code"); }

      // first check the database to make sure 
      // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
      $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_name='$username' OR user_email='$email' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
      $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      if ($user) { // if user exists
        if ($user['user_name'] === $username) {
          array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }

        if ($user['user_email'] === $email) {
          array_push($errors, "email already exists");
        }
      }

      // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
      if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

        $query1 = "INSERT INTO `users` (user_name, user_email, user_password, user_register_time) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', 'time()')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query1);

        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_name='$username' LIMIT 1";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
        $new_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $user_id = $new_user['user_id'];

        $planet_found = false;

        while (!$planet_found) {
            $galaxy = mt_rand(1, 1);
            $system = mt_rand(1, 15);
            $planet = mt_rand(1, 15);

            $query3 = "SELECT * FROM `planets` WHERE planet_galaxy='$galaxy' AND planet_system='$system' AND planet_planet='$planet' LIMIT 1";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($db, $query3);
            $planet_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

            if (!$planet_result) {
                $planet_found = true;
            }
        }

        $query4  = "INSERT INTO `planets` (planet_user_id, planet_galaxy, planet_system, planet_planet) VALUES('$user_id', '$galaxy', '$system', '$planet')";
        $result4 = mysqli_query($db, $query4);

        $query5  = "SELECT * FROM `planets` WHERE planet_user_id='$user_id' LIMIT 1";
        $result5 = mysqli_query($db, $query5);
        $planets_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5);
        $planets_id = $planets_info['planet_id'];

        $query6  = "UPDATE `users` SET user_home_planet_id='$planets_id', user_galaxy='$galaxy', user_system='$system', user_planet='$planet' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
        $result6 = mysqli_query($db, $query6);

        //update tables with new ids here


        $_SESSION['username']   = $username;
        $_SESSION['success']    = "You are now logged in";
        header("Location: ../");
      } else {
          header("Location: ../");
      }
    }       
?>
```

Yes, this is currently working; but I am sure I could break it. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

In general the code checks if a user exists or not. If not, it adds them to a user database and then creates a random location for them to live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few pointers:

### functions

You've put everything in the global scope of PHP. For small applications this can be tolerated but it quickly gets out of hand. Weird bugs will happen that are hard to track down, because you lost control of your variables. One sign that you're aware of this problem is the numbering of your variables: `$result1`, `$result2`, `$result3`, etc. It is better to perform each query inside the confines of a function and only, if needed, return the result.

### Don't repeat yourself (DRY principle)

There's a lot of repetion in your code. By gathering very similar code in a function you can make your code better readable, get the benefits of functions and make making alterations easier. For instance: You repeat this pattern a couple of times:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column = value LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$data   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You can put that in a function:

```
function retrieveDataRow($db,$table,$column,$value)
{
  $query  = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = $value LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
  return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

This is just an easy example, do read the `sql-injection` paragraph futher down. My point is that you can write this function once and then use its functionality several times. Also, suppose you want to do something about the sql-injection problem, now you only have to deal with this problem in one place instead of many places.

### classes

Talking about structure, why not use the object-oriented interface of mysqli, instead of the procedural interface? I don't believe this was a conscious choice. You'll find, when using PHP, that almost everything is written using classes, so it seems logical to use the object-oriented interface of mysqli as well. In the end it is your choice, but you have to think about this. See:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

### error checking

If all goes well your code will perform well, but what if a problem occurs, how will your code handle this? Not well, in my opinion. You don't check the result of query executions. For instance: `mysqli_query()` will return `FALSE` on failure, not an associative data array. At least check that:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
if ($result !== FALSE) {
  .... your code ....
} else error('Query error: '.mysqli_error($db));
```

### sql-injection

You insert your variables directly in the query strings. These cannot be called 'parameterized queries`. Books have been written about this, but basically mysqli uses binding of parameters to prevent sql-injection, see:

https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

but there are many other sources. This is a very common mistake to make.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will start working on your suggestions and reading the articles. I come from programming ladder logic, so this whole object-oriented programming is new to me. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea what ladder logic is.... <searching> ah, some kind of visual programming language. It does indeed look very different. Oh, please note that you've got some downvotes on your question, that's because this is not the right place for this type of question. It would be better suite for this community: https://codereview.stackexchange.com (but make sure your code works when you put it there).

Comment: Haha, yeah, ladder logic is for PLCs mostly. I did not even know codereview existed. I will move it over there once I implement your suggestions if is this is not the appropriate place. Appreciate all the help.